# Disable firestore in ios dev Schema

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a swift project, here is what I am trying to do:
I have a service class, responsible for saving data to firestore (bulk insert or single insert).
The service is used in a couple of viewControllers.
When using my dev schema I would like the app not writing anything to Firestore.

At the moment I have a env variable that act as a flag and in each function in my service I need to check if whether is set or not for saving data

```
func singleInsert(collection: String, data: [String: Any], id: String?) {
    if !isLoggingEnabled {
       // just print some stuff
       return
    }
    // save my data in firestore
}
```

It works.. but it is really ugly, I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. It is worth notice that I want to disable firestore only within my service class. There are instances in the app (which don't use the service) where firestore need to be always enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using something close to a factory pattern.

```
class RealTimeEventFactory {

    var realTimeEventServiceImpl: RealTimeEventProtocol

    init(isLoggingEnabled: Bool, errorHandler: ErrorHandlerProtocol) {
        if isLoggingEnabled {
            self.realTimeEventServiceImpl = RealTimeEventService(errorHandler: errorHandler)
        } else {
            self.realTimeEventServiceImpl = RealTimeEventServiceMock()
        }
    }
}
```

So I have two services both conforming to same protocol. Based on the isLoggingEnabled flag the factory will generate the required instance.

It's not perfect but seems to work fine